# alarmmanager android not working well

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I want to run task every X Days after the user press the button

there's my code but it doesn't work with me

OnButtonClick

```
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.YEAR);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MONTH);
                calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Calendar.MINUTE);
                calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);

                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                Intent i = new Intent(ActionsActivity.this, SuggestService.class);
                PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(ActionsActivity.this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
                //startService(i);
```

alarm class

```
public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver 
{    
 @SuppressLint("Wakelock")
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
 {   
     PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
     PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
     wl.acquire();

     // Put here YOUR code.
     Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm !!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     wl.release();
 }

 public void SetAlarm(Context context)
 {
     AlarmManager am =(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
     Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
     PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
     am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 10 * 1, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
 }
```

Service Class

```
public class SuggestService extends Service
{
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();       
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
{
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    return START_STICKY;
}


@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
{
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
    wl.acquire();

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Alarm !!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    wl.release();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
{
    return null;
}
}
```

OnClick the Toast show immediately !! :(

anyone can help ?

Comment: I think you should show more code - in snippet above I can't see any Toast called during onClick()

Comment: @AndreyKopeyko it's in **onReceive** method

Comment: @AndreyKopeyko i don't want the Toast show onClick ,   I want it after X time after Click

Comment: Toast - yes, I see. But still no `onClick()` method shown.

Comment: @AndreyKopeyko i forgot to put the method header , it's the first paragraph code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least one problem is the `Calendar` you are using. This line:

```
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

gets a `Calendar` instance with the current time. You then set the year to "1" with this line...

```
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.YEAR);
```

Because `Calendar.YEAR` = "1" ... And these other lines do similar "weird" settings.

```
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MONTH);
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Calendar.MINUTE);
```

Don't use any of those, just do this:

```
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
```

Comment: when I do this it's repeated every hour @NextMinute how to fix this and work only one time ?  thank you

Comment: You asked why it wasn't working, which I answered. You set the alarm to repeat with this line:      am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 10 * 1, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
Why would expect it to not repeat?? I think this is a separate question, right?

Comment: Okey, Thank you , (y)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem arrives because the alarm triggers immediately after it was set.

I had this problem in my code, and I conquered it by slightly shifting alarm time to the future:

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 5*1000,
                MAINTENANCE_INTERVAL,
                pendingIntent);
```